# Getting closest matching tuple (only lower) from a list of tuples

Tags: python

From a list of tuples I want to get the closest for a given value. However I not only want the closest but it must also be lower.

Let me give an example:

```py
my_list = [
  (1, "a"),
  (10, "b"),
  (40, "c"),
  (60, "d"),
]
```

Let's assume I want to get the closest lower tuple for value `35`.
The expected result in this case is `[10, "b"]`

I have tried the following, but this will return the closest matching, in this case `[40, "c"]`

```py
value = 35
min(my_list, key=lambda v: value - v[0])
```

Comment: Is it a `list of tuples` or `list of lists`

Comment: Sorry it is actually a `tuple` in my real code, but I typed a list in my example. Will edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a tuple from your `key` sorting function.

The `min` function will compare values using the first element of the tuple (is the value actually lower than the target?) and then use the second element to solve ties (how close is the value to the target?).

```py
value = 35
min(my_list, key=lambda v: (v[0] > value, value - v[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, this is working perfectly.